# MongoDb aggregate: Select all group by x

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to convert the following SQL-like statement into a mongo-query, using the new [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/).

```
SELECT * FROM ...
GROUP BY class
```

So far I have managed to write the following, which works well - yet only a single field is selected / returned.

```
db.studentMarks.aggregate(
   {
     $project: {
        class : 1 // Inclusion mode
     }
   },
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$class"
     }
   }
);
```

I have also attempted play with the $project pipelines [exclusion mode](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project), by adding a field name which never exists, in order to trick MongoDb to return all the fields. While the syntax is correct, no results are returned. E.g:

```
db.studentMarks.aggregate(
   {
     $project: {
        noneExistingField : 0 // Exclusion mode...
                              // Attempt to trick mongo into returning all fields
                              // sadly this fails - empty array is returned.
     }
   },
   {
     $group: {
        _id: "$class"
     }
   }
);
```

The reason why I need all fields to be returned, is that I will not know (in the future) what fields are going to be present or not. E.g. a "student" might have field x, y, z or not. Thus, I need to "select all", group the results by a single field and return it, for a generic purpose - doesn't have to be for "student marks", can be for any type of dataset, without knowing all the fields.

For the mentioned reason, I cannot simply project all the fields which must be returned - once again - because I will not know all the fields.

I hope that someone knows a good way of solving my problem, using the new aggregation framework.

Comment: From reading your question, you don't seem to have checked out the SQL Aggregation Mapping chart - http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/SQL%20to%20Aggregation%20Framework%20Mapping%20Chart.html. There's loads of information in there.

Comment: I did take a good look at them, and while I have no issues performing all of those stated examples, I do however still lack the ability to automatically project all fields, by entering exclusion mode. Please check http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/#_S_project. Maybe you can see something which I cannot...

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use the project operator in the pipeline.

```
db.studentMarks.aggregate({
  $group: { _id: "$class" }
});
```

Comment: well, but sometimes we really need that `$project`

Comment: This actually returns only the id in my case. Why?

Comment: Because you need to include the other fields that you want in the group. His question was specifically about just grouping and emitting the id.

Answer (score 0):

You can try group by all the fields push each to the array.

Try below.

### Option1

```
    `db.StudentMarks.aggregate( 
{
     $project: {
        class : 1 // Inclusion mode
     }
   }, 
{ $group : { 
        _id : "$class"
        ,field2: {$push: "$field2"}
        ,field3: {$push: "$field3"} 
        ,field4: {$push: "$field4"}
}}, $sort{field2:-1})`
```

I have not tried above, but below works for me.

### Option2

```
    `db.StudentMarks.aggregate( 
{
    { $group : { 
        _id : "$class"
        ,field2: {$push: "$field2"}
        ,field3: {$push: "$field3"} 
        ,field4: {$push: "$field4"}
}}, $sort{field2:-1})`
```

Result

```
    `{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 59,
                        "field2" : [
                                59,
                                59,
                                59
                        ],
                        "field3" : [
                                ObjectId("51e7072086eretetterr0001"),
                                ObjectId("51e7076786cb343453535354"),
                                ObjectId("51e716598435353534345335")
                        ],
                        "field4" : [
                                11111,
                                11111,
                                11111
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 58,
                        "field2" : [
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58,
                                58
                        ],
                        "field3" : [
                                ObjectId("51e469ad3843534535353535"),
                                ObjectId("51e7178f86cb349845667775"),
                                ObjectId("51e71df286cb349842456gtg"),
                                ObjectId("51e71ea686cb345646466466"),
                                ObjectId("51e71eac86cb346546464646")
                        ],
                        "field4" : [
                                11111,
                                11111,
                                11111,
                                11111,
                                11111
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}`
```